# how to read a csv like this using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have tried `pd.read_csv('../input/nasdaq-list/nasdaq-companies.csv',error_bad_lines=False,delimiter='\t')` but still with the same result.

Thanks.

Comment: try adding, ``sep=";"``

Comment: Could you please include a piece of the original CSV in the question, so others could reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should just use this:

```
pd.read_csv('../input/nasdaq-list/nasdaq-companies.csv', error_bad_lines=False, sep=';')
```

Answer (score 1):

The delimiter should probably be set to ';'

Hope it works!